# Protractor: Validate mandatory inputs or handling promises

Tags: validation, jasmine, protractor, angular-promise

I'm testing form with a couple of dozen inputs, mainly text-boxes. Several text inputs are mandatory in order to user create/edit accounts. However, I got pretty confused:

```
describe('Validation of mandatory fields', () => {

        it('validate first name input', () => {
            expertInfo.firstNameTextBox.click();
            expertInfo.firstNameTextBox.sendKeys(Key.CONTROL + 'a', Key.DELETE);
            expertInfo.firstNameTextBox.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
            expect(expertInfo.requiredFieldMessage.isPresent()).toBe(true); // this one pass
        });

        it('validate last name input', () => {
            expertInfo.lastNameTextBox.click().then(() => {
                expertInfo.lastNameTextBox.clear().then(() => {
                    expertInfo.save();
                    expect(expertInfo.requiredFieldMessage.isPresent()).toBe(true); // this one fails
                });
            });
        });
});
```

Any idea what is wrong with my approach? Am I handling promises properly? In the second test, the validation message does not appear and the user can edit/create an account.

Answer (score 1):

In protractor/jasmine there are 3 ways of handling asynchronous tasks,

1- Async/await

2- Promises

3- CallBacks
More info: https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async
Personal bias is towards async/await, as it is the simplest to keep track of. So in your code if you want to handle promises returned using async/await it would transform to:

```
describe('Validation of mandatory fields', () => {

    it('validate first name input', async () => {
       await expertInfo.firstNameTextBox.click();
       await expertInfo.firstNameTextBox.sendKeys(Key.CONTROL + 'a', 
       Key.DELETE);
       await expertInfo.firstNameTextBox.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
       expect(await expertInfo.requiredFieldMessage.isPresent()).toBe(true); 
    });

    it('validate last name input', async () => {
        await  expertInfo.lastNameTextBox.click();
        await expertInfo.lastNameTextBox.clear();
        await expertInfo.save();
        expect(await expertInfo.requiredFieldMessage.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    });
```

});

In the meantime, ask away!